# Background image not displaying in JLabel/JFrame in Java game

Tags: java, swing

I am making a java game and at it's heart, it consists of a JFrame that holds a a JLabel that holds the background image. Early in the project this was being displayed. However, after I implemented a Game render method that put healthbars and a character on screen, the background image no longer displays. Here is the Game's render() and main() methods.

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 1200, HEIGHT = 600, SCALE = 1;
    public static boolean running = false;
    public Thread gameThread;

    private BufferedImage playerSpriteSheet;
    private ImageManager im;

    private static Player player;
    private static HealthBar healthBars;

    public void init(){
        ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
        playerSpriteSheet = loader.load("/spriteSheet.png");
        SpriteSheet pss = new SpriteSheet(playerSpriteSheet);

        im = new ImageManager(pss);

        player = new Player(0, 0, im);
        healthBars = new HealthBar(200, 200);

        this.addKeyListener(new KeyManager());
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if(running)return;
        running = true;
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if(!running)return;
        running = false;
        try {
            gameThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        init();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        final double amountOfTicks = 60D;
        double ns = 1_000_000_000/amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long now = System.nanoTime();

        while(running)
        {
            delta += (now - lastTime)/ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if(delta >= 1)
            {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            render();
        }
        stop();
    }

    public void tick() {
        player.tick();
    }

    public void render() {

        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null)
        {
            createBufferStrategy(3); //Use 5 at most
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        //RENDER HERE
        player.render(g);
        healthBars.render(g);



        //END RENDER
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JLabel backgroundImage;
        JLabel controlKeyPanel;
        JLabel statusLabel;

        Game game = new Game();
        game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Game");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        backgroundImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/background.png"));

        String htmlButtonGuide = "<html>&#8592   -   Move Left<br>&#8594   -   Move Right<br>A  -  Attack<br>S  -  Fire Gun<br>P  -  Position<br>esc -   Exit</html>";
        controlKeyPanel = new JLabel(htmlButtonGuide);

        statusLabel = new JLabel("Game Status");


        frame.add(backgroundImage, BorderLayout.CENTER); //This should be displaying the background image
        frame.add(controlKeyPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(game);

        frame.setVisible(true);


        game.start();
    }

    public static Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

}
```

Here is the catch, and where I think part of the issue is visible. Inside the render() method there are these 2 lines:

```
player.render(g);
healthBars.render(g);
```

If I put player.render(g) first, then both the player and health bars appear on the screen. However, if I put healthBars.render(g) before player.render(g), then the player doesn't appear. This really confuses me, because I would expect the one that renders second causes the first one to be hidden behind, but the opposite happens. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `BufferStrategy` doesn't play well with `Swing`, as you've taken control of the painting process
- `Canvas` can't be transparent, so it will hide anything beneath it...
- When you use `frame.add(game)` you are replaceing what ever use to be at `BorderLayout.CENTER`

Instead of mixing lightweight (Swing) and heavy weight (AWT) components, paint the background image as part of your `render` process

```
public void render() {

    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null)
    {
        createBufferStrategy(3); //Use 5 at most
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    //RENDER HERE
    // Paint background here...
    player.render(g);
    healthBars.render(g);



    //END RENDER
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try to fix it in half an hour and let you know how it goes.